# How to set treeViewItem.name to 1.1

Tags: wpf, treeview

I am a newbie in wpf, I am using treeview but there are some different with winform. In treeview, I try to set treeviewItem.Name = "1.1" But it always say invalid. Is there anyway to pass it?

```
var node = new TreeViewItem();
node.Name = "1.1";
```

And the error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it, because of dot in variable name. See [General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions):

> DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric
>   characters.

May be you have wanted to set the `Header`, not the `Name` property?

```
var node = new TreeViewItem();
node.Header = "1.1";
```

Comment: I know there has a Header property, but I use header property for another purpose. The winform is not strictly this "name property" That why make me confuse when use wpf. I use the other way to do it change "1.1" to "A_1_1" and it's work :) Thanks Rekshino for your quick respond